# Why does this script work in FF and IE, but not in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a script which works perfectly fine in Firefox and IE 8/9. But it doesn't
work in Google Chrome.

Here is my script:

```
// At first I have a link at position x=500,y=400
<a href="http://www.google.de">TestLink</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function clicklink()
{
elementa = document.elementFromPoint(500, 400);
window.elementa.click();
}

window.setTimeout("clicklink()", 5000);

</script>
```

I have to solve this problem with the `ElementFromPoint` method because the link is a 
dynamic generated link from another side. So I can't use its `id` or `class`.

I'm open for a Javascript, jQuery, php or any other solution.

Edit:
I've also checked that it is the right position using this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_color_of_link()
{
elementb = document.elementFromPoint(500, 400);
elementb.style.color = 'red';
}

window.setTimeout("change_color_of_link()", 5000);

</script>
```

Chrome JS Console gave me this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'click'

Comment: possible duplicate of [document.elementFromPoint(x,y); not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904753/document-elementfrompointx-y-not-working)

Comment: Have you checked that the elementFromPoint returns the correct element, maybe the problem is that chrome renders the page differentley and the link is not in the right position?

Comment: please, avoid strings inside timeout. Use instead `window.setTimeout(clicklink, 5000);`

Comment: what is the window.elementa !!!!!!

Comment: Please, take a look on the Chrome JS console and you could definitely find an appropriate warning there. Please copy and paste it here

Comment: @Diodeus I think the other question talks about the `elementFromPoint` not working at all, this is different.

Answer (score 0):

The `click()` method is not part of the standard and does not exist in Chrome.

Instead, set `location = elementa.href`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what are you trying to do.

But if you only need/want to know when an anchor is "clicked" and can manipulate the html "around" the links, could you wrap the anchors in a div.

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#theDIV a").on("click",function(){
       //do your stuff here
  });
});
```

I mean, if you can put a DIV or know a DIV by ID that wrap the links, it could help you.