# jQuery - Mouseenter when element position changes

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

Consider the following code (jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7zEZw/))

```
<span class="content">foo</span><span class="closeButton">close</span>
<span class="content">bar</span><span class="closeButton">close</span>​

.content { padding: 0 4em; }
.closeButton:hover { display:inline; }
.closeButton {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: -3em;
}

​$('.content').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).next().css('display', 'inline');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).next().css('display', '');    
});
$('.closeButton').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prev().remove().end().remove();
});
​
```

When you mouse over the element 'foo' the closeButton appears using the jQuery 'mouseenter' event.  When you click the close button 'foo' is removed which causes the element 'bar' to move under the current location of the mouse.  However, the 'mouseenter' event does not fire for 'bar' until you move the mouse again.

Is there a good way to make it so that 'bar' receives this event immediately?

Consider that in this case you could remove multiple elements by simply clicking repeatedly.  Jittering the mouse in between clicks is a bad user experience.

I am aware of several near anwsers that will not work in my case.

1) The closeButton element is not actually contained inside of the 'foo' element that it closes.  This is required to avoid conflict with other scripts on the page and prevents using css :hover to display the button initially, which would work [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLZJx/). :(

2) I know a little about DOMMutationEvents, their deprecation, and relative lack of support and I would like to avoid them and the various timer hacks to emulate them etc.  I'm hoping that this problem is specific enough (a mouse location related event) to fire when the document has reflowed and modified the mouses target.  Especially since obviously the CSS engine knows about it and handles it properly.

3) I am using jQuery to modify the page.  I could monkey patch it to fire an event when I call 'remove()' and make sure that I "true up" all my other events.  This could work but the  remove could effect a large piece of the DOM and so it would be difficult to really pass any context into the handler.  As a result I would have to do a lot of extra work, rather than just processing one event for the one element under the mouse.  This might work now but be un-manageable later.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Which browser are you using? It works well for me on Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried running .trigger('mouseover') on the element in question, after moving?

Comment: @ahren I am testing with chrome on a mac.  Does it work on windows?  Be very careful not to move your mouse at all after the first click to close 'foo'.

also make sure you're looking at the first fiddle, not the example of a near fix that I can't use.

Comment: @BryanMoyles I could manually trigger, but what do I trigger the event on?  The button/function that performs the close doesn't necessarily know which other element is going to land under the cursor.

Comment: Yes I'm using Windows7/Chrome. Can't get it not to fire =)

Comment: @ahren I edited my last comment, so i'll repeat.  you are looking at the first fiddle where the closeButton is NOT contained inside the 'foo' span?

Comment: correct, I'm looking at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zEZw/

Comment: maybe I should file a 'bug' in jQuery then.  I wonder if they can polyfill that over on the mac, too.  It doesn't appear to work in my Safari, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a nifty method called document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY)

You'll see how I've used it at the JSfiddle here :) http://jsfiddle.net/7zEZw/1/

Comment: OOOH, SHINY!  this is well supported across browsers?

Comment: Looks good - but from what I can immediately find available about it, it may not be so well supported- yet! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904753/document-elementfrompointx-y-not-working

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html Check out this compatibility spec sheet, it actually is supported in a good handful of the common browsers

Comment: hmmm.  looks very promising.  I still kinda think it should fire on it's own (ideally) rather than me having to fire manually.  Maybe worth patching into jQuery whenever it changes the dom, since mouseenter is a jquery normalized event anyway.  I'll have to look into that.

Comment: Well I'm glad this got you partially there :) Just food for thought, you could potentially run a check on the position of the ".next()" element, compared to the mouse positioning of the current element, after you hide it, and then base your trigger off of that. I'm all for jquery building it in, but its a potential alternative solution :)